# wxListCtrl with multiple selections gives wrong result

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I use Code::Blocks 20.3, wxWidgets 3.1.4, and MinGW 17.1 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

I use ListCtrl (wxLC_REPORT mode) as criteria selector for a SQL server.
Wondering why my code sometimes generates wrong results, I created a small test app.
Just to see what is happening.

My problem occurs when I have selected multiple items.
When I click on an item that is not in Selected state, everything is OK.
When I click on an item in the set of already selected items, I get the result of all selected items instead of the one I selected.
It happens because the Focused state (also Selected state) is activated before the DeSelects have completed.
(see test below)

The code:

I created a ListControl with 4 items (Alyshia, Beatrice, Catherine, Daniella) with 3 events (OnSelected, OnDeSelected, OnFocused) and an Output function.

```
void ListCtrlFrame::OutputToConsole()
{
    long itemIndex = -1;
    while((itemIndex = m_listCtrl1->GetNextItem(itemIndex, wxLIST_NEXT_ALL, wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED)) != wxNOT_FOUND)
    {
        std::cout << "OUTPUT: "<< m_listCtrl1->GetItemText(itemIndex) << std::endl;
    }
}

void ListCtrlFrame::m_listCtrl1OnListItemSelected( wxListEvent& event )
{
    ListStateSelected = m_listCtrl1->GetItemState(event.m_itemIndex, wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED); // 4
    std::cout << ListStateSelected << " Selected: " << m_listCtrl1->GetItemText(event.m_itemIndex) << std::endl;
}

void ListCtrlFrame::m_listCtrl1OnListItemDeselected( wxListEvent& event )
{
    ListStateDeSelected = m_listCtrl1->GetItemState(event.m_itemIndex, wxLIST_STATE_DONTCARE ); // 0
    std::cout << ListStateDeSelected << " DeSelected: " << m_listCtrl1->GetItemText(event.m_itemIndex) << std::endl;
}

void ListCtrlFrame::m_listCtrl1OnListItemFocused( wxListEvent& event )
{
    ListStateFocused = m_listCtrl1->GetItemState(event.m_itemIndex, wxLIST_STATE_FOCUSED ); // 2
    std::cout << ListStateFocused << " Focused: " << m_listCtrl1->GetItemText(event.m_itemIndex) << std::endl;
    OutputToConsole();
}
```

The test:

```
Click on Alyshia -> Output is OK (1 item)
Ctrl + Click on Beatrice -> Output is OK (2 items)
Ctrl + Click on Catherine -> Output is OK (3 items)
then:
Click on (in selected state) Beatrice -> Output is Wrong (3 instead of 1 item)
What happens is that the Output is generated before the deselection of the others (see below)
```

Output:

```
2 Focused: Alyshia
OUTPUT: Alyshia
4 Selected: Alyshia

4 Selected: Beatrice
2 Focused: Beatrice
OUTPUT: Alyshia
OUTPUT: Beatrice

4 Selected: Catherine
2 Focused: Catherine
OUTPUT: Alyshia
OUTPUT: Beatrice
OUTPUT: Catherine

2 Focused: Beatrice
OUTPUT: Alyshia
OUTPUT: Beatrice
OUTPUT: Catherine
0 DeSelected: Alyshia
0 DeSelected: Catherine
```

Comment: do you have access to another Windows version? Can you test there? Can you build and run the `listctrl` sample provided with wxWidgets? (in the future - no need to create a sample, just run one provided with the library) Can you reproduce it there?

Comment: I built the ListCtrl sample. It is behaving exactly the same way.

Comment: ( first OnFocused after that, 2x OnDeSelected.) Sorry, no other windows version anywhere near :-(.

Comment: BTW: My Windows 10 version is 1909 18363.1016

Comment: you might want to send an e-mail to wx-users to confirm that this is bug, before filing it officially in the trac.wxwidgets.org. When you do - explain how to see the issue in the sample. You will need to register in order to send this e-mail.

Comment: Instead of `wxListCtrl` prefer `wxListView` as suggested https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#a172d78854092aec2b784b8519bf5be08